# How do I force the Dns.GetHostAddresses .NET method to only query DNS or the DNS cache?

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, networking, dns

When I run the following DNS query in PowerShell on a server using the .NET GetHostAddresses method, I get the following:

```
([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("hostname")).ipaddresstostring
10.10.10.55
```

I am running this query REMOTELY.

However, when I run the same exact query LOCALLY on the actual server itself, I get the following:

```
([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("hostname")).ipaddresstostring
10.10.10.55
10.10.34.101
10.10.138.154
```

Clearly, it's giving me the IP address of the additional interfaces that are not registered in DNS because I am running the method locally.

So, my question is, how can I force the method to ONLY query DNS or a DNS cache rather than query the localhost info first? Put otherwise, how do I can I run this method locally on a server to get the output it would give me had I run it remotely?

I only want the IP address that is associated with DNS regardless of whether or not I run it remotely or locally.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using just the hostname, or the FQDN?

Comment: I've tried both, and same result.

Comment: Does GetHostEntry() return the same thing in the AddressList?

Comment: Effectively, yes. I have to call [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry("hostname").addresslist, but that will give the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Another "hooky" way:

```
function dnsLookup($hostname){
    $r = (nslookup $hostname | Out-String).split("`n")
    for($i = 4; $i -lt ($r.count - 2); $i++){
    $r[$i] -replace "Address:  |Addresses:  | |`t",""
    }   
}
```

So running `dnsLookup YourHost` will yield required result but it is a dirty workaround.

Comment: Just gave that a shot, same result. I'm not concerned whether or not is queries the cache or live DNS, I want to force it to not query the localhost first. I'm thinking that the order the methods attempts to query is localhost > DNS cache > live DNS. I want to cut out the localhost query.

Comment: Amended the answer to a not very pretty(but working) solution.

Comment: I see what you're trying to do, but that does not work.

Comment: Another shot up there using nslookup, that should do it but it doesn't use _[System.Net.Dns]_ class.

Comment: I found another solution, but yours deserves an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to query the DNS cache, you might need to use the `DnsQuery()` method in the Win32 API, and use .NET P/Invoke to call it from PowerShell. See this StackOverflow question: [Retrieving what's in the DNS cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998176/retrieving-whats-in-the-dns-cache)