# Powershell returning more than what is in DNS

Tags: powershell

I am trying to match a registry entry with what is in DNS on a multi-homed server.  The problem is system.net.dns seems to return more then what is in DNS.

Example:

```
nslookup hostname.dns.net
Server DNS.server.naem
Address: IP.Address.of.server

Name: hostname.dns.net
Address: single.ip.of.server
```

However when I use:

```
$DNSResult = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($Computer)
$DNSresult.addresslist
```

It outputs 2 both of the server IP addresses, the published one and the unpublished one....

What do I do to only get the result as published by DNS.

Comment: Maybe this will help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842082/how-do-i-force-the-dns-gethostaddresses-net-method-to-only-query-dns-or-the-dns/22842379#22842379

Comment: Thank you if there is no way to fix the system call I may have to go this route but I hope not.

Comment: Tying the method you attached however running in to problems:
    $computername=$env:COMPUTERNAME
    function dnsLookup($hostname){
    $r = (nslookup $hostname | Out-String).split("`n")
    for($i = 4; $i -lt ($r.count - 2); $i++){
    $r[$i].replace("Address:  ","").replace("Addresses:  ","").replace(" ","").replace("`t","")
        }   
    }
    [Net.IPAddress]$dnsip=dnsLookup $computername
    $dnsip
I get the error:
Cannot convert value "10.0.0.1" to type "System.Net.IPAddress". Error: "An invalid IP address was specified."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re `Net.IPAddress]$dnsip=dnsLookup $computername $dnsip` error. I added a line feed character cleanup, it was hiding at the end of the output and prevented correct parsing. The output from nslookup is broken down into array of strings. With `$i = 4` you start processing the output on line 5, ie the one where the first returned address will be. `$r.count - 2` stops processing the last line, an empty string.

```
function dnsLookup($hostname){
    $r = (nslookup $hostname | Out-String).split("`n")
    for($i = 4; $i -lt ($r.count - 2); $i++){
        $r[$i] -replace ("Address:  |Addresses:  | |`t|`r|Server"),""
    }
}
```

Now `Net.IPAddress]$dnsip=dnsLookup $computername` will work.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Can you explain how this works? I understand the striping of all information and spaces from the results of the NSLookup but what is this doing:
    ($i = 4; $i -lt ($r.count - 2); $i++)