# Is there a way to monitor the system's DNS cache on c#?

Tags: c#, caching, windows-7, dns

I want to do a real time monitor of the DNS cache requests of the system in c#.
My system is a windows 7 64 bit.
What I did so far is to catch the DNS requests by creating a listening UDP server on port 53, but this monitors ALL the DNS request, what I am interested in are only request made to DNS cache of the local OS. Is there a way to monitor the DNS cache of the system?
THx

Comment: Maybe this post can be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998176/retrieving-whats-in-the-dns-cache. It's about reading the cache with an API. Maybe it provides signalling.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your DNS cache via this powershell function: [Show-DnsServerCache](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649915.aspx)

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527513/execute-powershell-script-from-c-sharp-with-commandline-arguments) SO post illustrates how to call powershell functions from C#.

Comment: Yes, thx for the answer but it seems that it can be an option but only for Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows 8.1.