# Any way to get the DNS cache entries in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, dns

I've been looking for answers and couldn't quite find anything that worked for me, hopefully there's someone who can help me out with this.

I need to get the number of entries in the DNS cache of the computer. Not really even interested in the particular entries, just the total count.

This answer ([Is there a way to monitor the system's DNS cache on c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26605690/is-there-a-way-to-monitor-the-systems-dns-cache-on-c)) comes close but I can't manage to download the powershell module to try to get it to work, plus it would be best if I could get a solution that worked without requiring any extra tools to be installed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Powershell is part of Windows. You don't have to download it. The link in the post you linked contains a link to TechNet that gives a 404, but has a list of possible related pages, and the very first one in the list is the one you want. That same answer has a link to sample code for using Powershell from C#. What more do you need?

Comment: The dnsserver module containing Show-DnsServerCache is not in my computer (at least I can't access it, PowerShell says it's not there and so on).
For what I have gathered it might be in the Windows Servers but for the others you have to download it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to do it by using the PowerShell Get-DnsClientCache function.

DnsClient functions are apparently loaded by default in the non-server Windows OSs as well, unlike the dnsserver module.

Anyone interested can see an example on how to execute PowerShell scripts in the link posted in the original question.